# how to shadow the recycler view and fab button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am searching in SO and try to add shadow for `RecyclerView` and `fab` button.I got the command `android:elevation` and `android:line` provider for shadowing the `recycler view` but nothing happens by using the command

What I am trying

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorgrey"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.karthi.nestaway.MainActivity">
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:outlineProvider="bounds"
                android:background="@color/colorwhite
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"  />
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: As far as I know elevation only works on API 21 or above. Are you testing on a device or emulator of at least Android 5.0 ?

Comment: i am using android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

> Attribute elevation is only used in API level 21 and higher check your API level.

In your Manifest file inside `application` tag add

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Increase the value of `android:elevation` to see shadow effects.

Hope this helps.